# Setting Default in the Dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select

I am trying to set a default in to the below drop down

```
<div hidden id="projectSelected">
    <label style="font-size: medium">Project *</label>
    <select name="projectSelected" id="projectSelectedId" class="form-control" 
        ng-model="request.projectSelectedBarcode" required>
        <option ng-repeat="prj in projectList" value="{{prj.Barcode}}">{{ prj.Name }}</option>
    </select>
    <div style="color:maroon" ng-messages="getServiceReuqestForm.projectSelected.$error"
        ng-if="getServiceReuqestForm.projectSelected.$touched">
        <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here `projectList` is the data returned from the Odata call. Is it possible that I can have one of the returned values as default in to my dropdown.

Comment: You should use ng-options directive, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194255/how-to-have-a-default-option-in-angular-js-select-box

Comment: @niklaz I am new to Angular. Should I be using them along with the ng-repeat?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088227/angularjs-set-default-value-on-select-inside-a-ng-repeat

Comment: @levininja I dont have the control over the list of values from the dropdown as it is the data returned from a Odata Web service.

Comment: @trx, you don't need to use ng-repeat, since ng-options directive uses is  internally. Check docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is set your select's ng-model to be one of the Barcode from your Odata values.

Say that after the Odata call you have something like this :

```
$scope.projectList=[
{
    "Name":"project 1",
  "Barcode":"barcode 1"
},
{
    "Name":"project 2",
  "Barcode":"barcode 2"
},
{
    "Name":"project 3",
  "Barcode":"barcode 3"
}];
```

Then you just have to do something like this :

```
  $scope.request={
   "projectSelectedBarcode":$scope.projectList[2].Barcode
  }
```

And that should set your `<select>`

You can have a look at this JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Freego/p7g2d08g/1/

Hope this helps !